# Insert into Select with Two Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to allocate students to respective exam centers.

Is there any way for doing this?

I have 2 tables:

**Student**

```
| StudentID  | StudentName | AllocatedCenter |
```

**ExamCenter**

```
|  CenterID  |    Center Name    |<br>
```

I am trying with `Insert Into Select` statement but with two different parameters as follows:

Correct query should be:

```
INSERT INTO Student (AllocatedCenter)
    SELECT CenterName 
    FROM ExamCenter 
    WHERE CenterID = 5;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Student (AllocatedCenter) 
WHERE StudentID = 1
    SELECT CenterName 
    FROM ExamCenter 
    WHERE CenterID = 5;
```

But this is syntactically wrong statement although I want to insert only for a particular `StudentID`

Is there any solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you want to `update` the table `Student` instead of inserting new records, right?

Comment: Yes, I need to use UPDATE Statement for inserting the record in last column which was kept NULL from the time of table creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may looking for simple update

```
UPDATE S
SET AllocatedCenter =(SELECT TOP 1 [Center Name] FROM ExamCenter WHERE  CenterID= 5 ORDER BY CenterID)
FROM Student s
WHERE StudentID= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the existing records then you have to use UPDATE not INSERT

If you want to update the centername for record where studentId = 1 then 
    query is

```
UPDATE Student set AllocatedCenter = 
(select CenterName from ExamCenter
 where CenterID=5)
WHERE StudentID = 1;
```